# Cannot view the nodes I created using py2neo using a cypher query in the browser

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am creating nodes using py2neo as follows:

```
from py2neo import neo4j 
graph_db =  neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data")

print graph_db.neo4j_version
graph_db.clear()

if not graph_db.get_index(neo4j.Node, "Kiran"):
        from py2neo import node,rel
        trial = graph_db.create(
        node(name="Kiran"),
        node(name="teja"),
        rel(0, "Brother", 1),
        )

#else:
details = graph_db.get_index(neo4j.Node, "Kiran")
print details
```

the get_index returns me some data like

```
Index(Node, u'http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/Kiran')
```

but when I search for the node on the browser, it returns me nothing...
am I doing something wrong here?

also I am trying to publish some network information as follows :

```
from py2neo import neo4j
from py2neo import node,rel
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data")

def nodepublish(dpid, port, mac):
  if graph_db.get_index( neo4j.Node, dpid ) == None:
    create = graph_db.create({"DPID": dpid})
    print "switch "+str(dpid)+" added to graph"
  if graph_db.get_index( neo4j.Node, mac ) == None:
    query = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, "MATCH (sw) WHERE sw.DPID = "+str(dpid)+" CREATE (nd {MAC: "+str(mac)+"}) CREATE (sw)-[:connected {PORT: "+str(port)+"}]->(nd)")
    print "node "+str(mac)+" added to graph"
```

When I call the nodepublish() function like

```
nodepublish(1,1,"aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa")
```

It creates a new node with dpid:1 every time instead of skipping the if statement once the get_index doesn't return None.

can someone help me out with this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point no 1**: make sure you have a trailing slash on your GraphDatabaseService URI. You may get incorrect results without it.

**Point no 2**: you are using **legacy indexes** here. Be clear about which type of index you are using by reading [this](http://nigelsmall.com/neo4j/index-confusion).

I think you have mixed up *indexes* and *index entries*. An *index* (perhaps called `People` in this instance) points to a set of entries, each identified by a key-value pair. At each entry point, you may reference one or more nodes. Read more on legacy indexes [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html).

You probably want your code to look more like this:

```
from py2neo import neo4j 
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

# Create a "People" index if one doesn't already exist
people = graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "People"):

# Create two people nodes if they don't already exist
kiran = people.get_or_create("name", "Kiran", {"name": "Kiran"})
teja = people.get_or_create("name", "Teja", {"name": "Teja"})

# Relate the two
brothers, = graph_db.create((kiran, "BROTHER", teja))

print kiran
print teja
print brothers
```

[This page](http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/indexes/) might help with some of the details in the code as it describes the legacy index functions that you need here.

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you. I have a doubt: what does the brothers, = signify? I searched for it and couldn't find anything.

Comment: The `create` method always returns a list, even when only one thing is being created. This is explicitly mentioned in the docs -> http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/graphs_nodes_relationships/#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.create

Comment: I have another question: say I have a node{"name": "john smith" , "city": "houston", "age" : "31" } and I got a new entry to publish for the same john smith but with a different city and I want to publish the new node and copy the remaining properties from the old node and delete it.

how would i do it?
>>>>
If a node exists with the same name:
  if the properties differ:
    create a new node and copy the properties and delete the old node

  else:
    do nothing
>>>>
how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can't easily in a single step, but you probably don't want to anyway. Read up on *labels*, *schema indexes*, *unique constraints* and the Cypher `MERGE` keyword. Then post a new StackOverflow question for any bits you can't work out from the docs and experimentation.

Comment: I run this answer and I get this error:                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    people = graph_db.get_or_create_index("People")
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'get_or_create_index'